# What's the best way to load large JSON lists in Python?

Tags: python, json, large-files

I have access to a set of files (around 80-800mb each).  Unfortunately, there's only one line in every file.  The line contains exactly one JSON object (a list of lists).  What's the best way to load and parse it into smaller JSON objects?

Comment: This question is closed as a duplicate because the accepted answer here, is an exact duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052983/7758804).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7052947/1332690). Here is the solution they proposed:

```py
import json
with open('file.json') as infile:
  o = json.load(infile)
  chunkSize = 1000
  for i in xrange(0, len(o), chunkSize):
    with open('file_' + str(i//chunkSize) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(o[i:i+chunkSize], outfile)
```

Comment: killed, this is what python shell said

Comment: The questions asks *"load and parse it into smaller JSON objects"*, not *"dump to one output file"*. Here you're just splitting the raw JSON input into fixed-length chunks, those individual chunks will almost surely not be parseable as legal JSON.

Answer (score 8):

The module `pandas 0.21.0` now supports chunksize as part of `read_json`. You can load and manipulate one chunk at a time:

```
import pandas as pd
chunks = pd.read_json(file, lines=True, chunksize = 100)
for c in chunks:
    print(c)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, so try ijson instead. Using python3.7 and a 170 MB file on a constrained t1.micro instance, this exact pandas command returns the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 765, in __next__
    obj = self._get_object_parser(lines_json)
...
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
MemoryError

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to avoid loading the whole list into memory, you could process the file as text first:

Use a stack to keep track of open and closing of brackets/quotes. Scan through the string for any of the openers, or the current closer. When scanning through text, look only for the text closer. Push one on when you read the opener, and pop it off when you find the closer.

The full set for JSON is `[` -> `]`, `{` -> `}` and `"` -> `"`. You should exclude `\"` though. You can check the spec at http://www.json.org/

Then whenever a `]` is encountered and the stack only has one item (the top level '[') after popping the matching `[`, then you know it's time to start a new line.

Finally, you should ensure the first `[` and last `]` don't appear in your output.

That will give you separate JSON objects for each item of the list, each on a separate line of the file.

If you dig into the python JSON library, there should be some functions that parse JSON too. You could leverage those, even though they aren't part of the public interface.

Of course, you can achieve the same by loading the string using the JSON library and then dumping it item by item (or multiple items) as per the other answer.

Comment: Why would this low level scanning approach be necessary when a perfectly good json module comes with the standard lib? See @linker's answer

Comment: i presume that he does not want to have the memory overhead of having the json object actually stored in memory. the public interface of the json library doesnt allow that. I do mention though that he could hack into that library and use some of the helper functions, though i havent looked at them.

Comment: Yes but the memory concern isn't really an issue for a one time batch processing as suggested in the other answer. It doesn't have to be a production solution to just batch it down to smaller objects.

Comment: that depends on the poster's situation. i shoudlnt have assumed that he knew about the python json library, but his question seems to imply that he didnt want to simply load it and dump each list item.

Comment: I actually wasn't considering that the OP did say specifically it would always be a json list of lists. So scanning char by char is reasonable if the OP does want to do this live. But again, if memory is not a consideration, then a json module using C speedups would parse much faster.

Comment: that's right. i've added some context to my answer to indicate what situations he might want to use this solution in. i guess we'll find out what his aims were when he accepts one of the answers.

Comment: @chees - you're correct, I'm looking for a way to parse into multiple management objects this without loading the entire object into memory.