# Python -Reading JSON large size data

Tags: python, json, r, bigdata

I would like to read JSON data ( 12 GB ) in Python / R .

If i used json.loads() function it gives a memory error.

I have no clue about the data . Is it possible to read a section of the data ?

Please help

Comment: You are not gonna be able to read 12 GB if you at least don't have more than that on the RAM.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pymotw.com/2/json/#working-with-streams-and-files

Comment: It's the data a single JSON object? Or can you split into smaller chunks?

Comment: Answer @Hamish's question, it's very important.

Comment: If the file is a bunch json objects on separate lines, then it is trivial to parse each line separately.  If not, you'll have to use a streaming parser (qiangwang and PepperoniPizza suggestions) that lets you watch the data as it gets parsed, keep what you need, and throw the rest away.

Comment: @Hamish- It is a single json file . It is the data of 6 million page views. I have little information about the schema i.e. the attributes of a page view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238340/whats-the-best-way-to-load-large-json-lists-in-python 
check this question, its explain how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/ This may help.

Search "python json sax parser", you can get other solutions.