# Load large JSON file into dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, large-files

I am trying to load some big JSON files into dataframes. I have been able to load files upto 450 MBs with about 2.2 million records. The biggest file I have got is about 800 MBs. When I try to load the biggest file, it crashes my container (with exit code 137).

I have tried the below two methods:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def load_json(jpath):
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in open(jpath, 'r')]
    print('JSON file has been loaded in memory')
    print()
    # df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    print('JSON has been loaded in Dataframe')
    return df2
```

and

```
def load_json2(jpath):
    data_iterator = pd.read_json(jpath, chunksize=100000, lines=True)
    chunk_list = []
    for data_chunk in data_iterator:
        filtered_chunk = data_chunk.filter(items=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
        chunk_list.append(filtered_chunk)
        print('chunk appended')
        print()

    df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
    return df
```

Second method seems to be quite slow. Takes forever to load the file with 450 MB size whereas method 1 takes less than a minute to load that file. But method 1 ends up in a container crash as well with 800 MB size file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a similar post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238340/whats-the-best-way-to-load-large-json-lists-in-python

Comment: Thanks Sagar. My problem is a bit different. I tried using 'ijson' but that fails with "additional data" error.